# skipping authentication/authorization for for the NIF URL nifi-api/system-diagnostics

Tags: apache-nifi

I want the an URL in NIFI
`https://aslog-nifi-test.app.corpintra.net/nifi-api/system-diagnostics` to be skipped from Authentication/Authorization. That means, whenever any user click the url which contains the page `nifi-api/system-diagnostics` it should skip the authorization and give the result. Currently this is going for authentication and then only giving the response.

Is it possible to do this setting in NIFI?